# how to check that a string isn't a keyword or type in c#

Tags: c#, types, keyword, identifier

I am writing a code generator in which the variable names are given by the user.

Previous answers have suggested using Regex or CodeDomProvider, the former will tell you if the identifier is valid, but doesn't check keywords, the latter checks keywords, but doesn't appear to check all Types known to the code.
[How to determine if a string is a valid variable name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829679/how-to-determine-if-a-string-is-a-valid-variable-name)

For instance, a user could name a variable `List`, or `Type`, but that is not desirable.  How would I prevent this?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but couldnt you just attempt to compile the code, and return whatever error the runtime threw up?

Comment: That's going to vary greatly with the namespaces that you've brought into the code with `using`.  Additionally, over time, those namespaces will add new types.  You can use reflection to find all of the classes in an assembly.

Comment: @asawyer: That might be a good solution.

Comment: @clintp the list of reserved words doesn't really vary, and dynamic compilation will return a list of errors, which he can filter for the ones that he is really concerned about ('Identifier expect, '***' is a keyword).

Comment: Seems the solutions are 1) add @ symbol or 2) compile or 3) make a list of all keywords.  3) though doesn't do what I'd like, as CodeDomProvider does this already, I believe.

Comment: @David The list of reserved words *does* vary. What may have been valid in one version, may become invalid in a new version.

Comment: @chibacity yes, but it doesn't vary very frequently (four times in ten years so far?). I wonder if there's a way to query the compiler for a list... Hmmm.

Comment: @David A single change is enough to break something. There has been a substantial amount of change to keywords: 1.0:?, 1.1:77, 2.0:83, 3.5:83, 4.0:102.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure there is a full API available which will give you what you're looking for.  However the end result you seem to be looking for is the generation of code which will not cause conflicts with reserved C# keywords or existing types.  If that is the case one approach you can take is to escape all identifiers given by the user with the `@` symbol.  This allows even reserved keywords in C# to be treated as identifiers.

For example the following is completely valid C# program

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int @byte = 42;
        int @string = @byte;
        int @Program = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to add a list of C# keywords to your application. MSDN has a complete list [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx).

If you really want to get fancy, you could [dynamically compile your generated code](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/4529/using-net-to-make-your-application-scriptable/3/) and check for the specific errors that you're concerned about. In this case, you're specifically looking for error [CS1041](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47dbdc1k.aspx):

> error CS1041: Identifier expected; '****' is a keyword

You'll probably want to ignore any errors regarding unresolved references, undeclared identifiers, etc.

As others have suggested, you could just prepend your identifiers with `@`, which is fine if you don't want the user to examine the generated code. If it's something they're going to have to maintain, however, I'd avoid that as (in my opinion) it makes the code noisy, just like `$` all over the place in PHP or guys that insist on putting `this.` in front of every freaking field reference.

Comment: And hope that the next version of C# doesn't add a new keyword that conflicts with something that your code generates.

Answer (score 2):

One option here would be to have your code generator prefix the user-specified name with `@`.  As [described in 2.4.2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670%28VS.71%29.aspx), the `@` sign (verbatim identifier):

> prefix "@" enables the use of keywords as identifiers, which is useful when interfacing with other programming languages. The character @ is not actually part of the identifier, so the identifier might be seen in other languages as a normal identifier, without the prefix. An identifier with an @ prefix is called a verbatim identifier. Use of the @ prefix for identifiers that are not keywords is permitted, but strongly discouraged as a matter of style.

This would allow you to check for the main keywords, and deny them as needed, but not worry about all of the conflicting type information, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could just prepend a `@` character to the variable - for instance, `@private` is a valid variable name.